# Will adding Google Calendar to your website make it not Static anymore?

Tags: html, google-calendar-api

I want to add my schedule to my website with google calendar, but I hosting my website on github. Github only supports static web pages. Is this gonna be a problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use server-side code on Github Pages. You can use client-side JavaScript.

So long as the dynamic Google Calendar code you are adding is client-side JavaScript, there won't be a problem hosting it on any static file server.

Comment: To elaborate, adding the Google Calendar embed/iframe is fine.